# Add a link to the community blog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, hyperlinks

This is a feature request to the Stack Exchange engine.

Currently the [top page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) of the site does not contain a link to the [community blog](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/).  I think that it should.

I expected that the link labeled “blog” at the bottom of the page takes the viewer to the community blog, but it links to http://blog.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: It seems that they have removed the link for the time being. I guess they were waiting for the blog to move to [blog.cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://blog.cstheory.stackexchange.com) to fix the link and will put it back when the blog is moved to its permanent URL (which is probably when they feel we will keep posting regularly on the blog).

Comment: @Kaveh: I do not know which URLs are permanent and which are not.  Does it mean that the problem will resolve automatically when/if the blog has more content?

Comment: It is explained [here](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/). The cstheory.blogoverflow.com is a temporary URL for the beta phase of the blog. It seems that after cstheory blog's graduation it will be moved to its permanent URL under blog.cstheory.SE and the links will be also fixed.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks for the information.

Comment: you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A link to the community blog will now appear in the top nav bar, for all users, when there is a new post (defined as a post that's under a day old).

Comment: Thanks Rebecca.

Comment: Sounds good.  Also the “blog” link at the bottom of the page now links to http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/.

Comment: Great! Thanks Rebecca.

Comment: awesome !! that's very cool.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [page](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/) in Kaveh’s comment, a blog at 〈site〉.blogoverflow.com is in beta.  When a blog graduates beta, it is moved to blog.〈site〉.stackexchange.com, and the link in the footer on the main site is changed to point to it.